# Long layover at Copenhagen Airport (CPH)

Tags: airports, layovers, sleeping, copenhagen, cph

I potentially might have a long layover (8:30 p.m to 7:00 a.m.) in November at CPH (Terminal 2). I would like to explore my options as to what I can do that night. If I can get a shower and places to eat/ drink at the airport, I'd like to skip getting a proper hotel and save some money. I've never been to CPH airport before, so any pointers/tips would be welcome.

Comment: Did you already have a read of the [sleeping in airports page for CPH](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/copenhagen_kastrup.htm)? What do you need to know beyond that?

Comment: I had not read it and It is very helpful. Thank you

Comment: From the given page, it seems there are no shower facilities at CPH airport but the airport is open 24 hours!

Comment: Yes, not very encouraging. I think, I'll have a get room at a hotel nearby.

Comment: [Plenty of cheap rooms available here in November](https://www.radissonblu.com/en/scandinaviahotel-copenhagen)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Showering at CPH

The Copenhangen Airport website carries no mention of public shower facilities, except for in the page specific to the [CPH Regus Business Lounge](https://www.cph.dk/en/before-travelling/workspace-and-lounges/regus-express/) which gives you a 2h access to the lounge, access to showers and a breakfast for 250`DKK`. You can also buy access to the lounge at 80`DKK` per hour. Prices are quoted at the time of writing.

There seem to be [sleeping rooms with showers in the SAS Gold Lounge](http://first2board.com/wanderlusty/2014/05/best-kept-secret-sas-copenhagen-lounge-day-bedrooms/), although [these won't be accessible overnight](http://www.flysas.com/en/us/travel-info/at-the-airport/lounges/list-of-lounges/) since all SAS lounges close 30 minutes before the last SAS flight leaves and open 60 minutes before the first SAS flight leaves the airport.

#### Eating at CPH

[The many restaurants at CPH](https://www.cph.dk/en/Shopping-and-tax-free/restaurants-bars-and-cafes/units/) are likely to be closed overnight, at roughly the same time as when the lounges are closed, although this is pure speculation since I could not find any information on opening times on the official airport website. Since you arrive at 20h30 you'll likely find them still open and active.

#### Sleeping at CPH

Sleeping at CPH is something that many people have done, as testified by the extensive list of reviews which can be found on the [Sleeping in Airports CPH page](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/europe/copenhagen_kastrup.htm). There are comfortable benches scattered around the terminals, some of which are conveniently located next to power plugs.

#### Hotels at CPH

Arguably the closest hotel is the [Hilton Copenhagen Airport](http://m.hilton.com/mt/www3.hilton.com/en/hotels/denmark/hilton-copenhagen-airport-CPHAPHI/index.html) which probably caters mostly to passengers with overnight layovers. Room prices are likely to be quite steep, especially of all you're looking for is a shower.